# (Google Play Billing Lib) - Timeout communicating with service when subscribing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I have my app published on internal, alpha, and beta.

I'm trying to subscribe by calling `billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow`.
But I'm getting:

**response code: -3, debug message: Timeout communicating with service.**

The Google Play account on the android physical device is added as a licensed tester.
I thought that could be the problem, I removed the email from the licensed tester list. But still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?
I'm sure it's not an internet connectivity problem, tried multiple networks.
The error message is clear "Timeout communicating with service.", but didn't detect the cause of that.

Using the billing lib v4.1.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google play billing service timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71503163/google-play-billing-service-timeout)

Comment: yes, I added this question before detecting the solution.